# PostgreSQL count how many late every month in a year

Tags: postgresql

I have this field named `late_in` that contains data like this 2017-05-29 08:36:44 where the limit for entry time is 08:30:00 every day.

What I want to do is to get the year, month and how many times he late in that month even if it zero late in the month.

I want the result look something like this:

```
year   month   late
-------------------
2017   1       6
2017   2       0
2017   3       14
```

and continue until the end of year.

Comment: What you mean `limit for entry time is 08:30:00 every day`. How this affects on desirable result ?

Comment: I mean my office entry time is 08:30:00 so more than that will be count as late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select extract(year from late_in) as year, 
       extract(month from late_in ) as month, 
       count(*) filter (where late_in::time > time '08:30:00') as late
from the_table
group by extract(year from late_in), 
         extract(month from late_in );
```

This assumes that `late_in` is defined as `timestamp`.

The expression `late_in::time` returns only the time part of the value and the `filter()` clause for the aggregation will result in only those rows being counted where the condition is true, i.e. where the time part is after 08:30

Comment: I think, you have to use where instead of when after filter. And remove select after group by.

Comment: thanks. works great. But is it possible to show a full month of year even if it is 0 late for the month?

Comment: @Faiz: that will show a zero count unless there is no row in that table for that month at all.